# Change table background color using google docs API (node.js)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am generating some reports using google docs and drive API. I want dynamically set the background color in my table cells based on how high or low a number is, the lower the number the more red color, the higher the number the more green.

**Take a look at this example:**

[image]

**I am able to update the numbers from my node service like this:**

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: 'credentials.json',
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
});

// Create client instance for auth
const client = await auth.getClient();
const docs = google.docs({ version: 'v1', auth: client });
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: client });

const copyMetaData = {
  name: `Some report`,
  parents: ['1b78gdfgdf8gdiokkg4XG2-9WFWGGla'] // some folder id
};

const copiedFile = await drive.files.copy({
  auth,
  fileId: '1VMKs89fg9AGP1xs-1F545gKgkvf2Daza7UZMRsdf789', // some file id
  requestBody: copyMetaData
});

const requests = [
  ['{{data-1}}', '447'],
  ['{{data-2}}', '378'],
  ['{{data-3}}', '102'],
  ['{{data-1-p}}', '91'],
  ['{{data-2-p}}', '78'],
  ['{{data-3-p}}', '23']
].map(update => {
  const [handleBar, replaceText] = update;
  return {
    replaceAllText: {
      containsText: {
        text: handleBar,
        matchCase: true
      },
      replaceText
    }
  };
```

I Just can't figure out how I can set background color, or even identify my table cells. Or whether this is even possible or not, but it seems like a quite trivial use case to me, as in all the googles examples they are generating invoices and you would easily think that one would want to make a negative balance bold and red, but but for example black if its a positive balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample request to [update table cell colors for Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%22INSERT_ID%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22updateTableCellStyle%22%3A%7B%22tableCellStyle%22%3A%7B%22backgroundColor%22%3A%7B%22color%22%3A%7B%22rgbColor%22%3A%7B%22green%22%3A1%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22backgroundColor%22%2C%22tableRange%22%3A%7B%22columnSpan%22%3A1%2C%22rowSpan%22%3A1%2C%22tableCellLocation%22%3A%7B%22columnIndex%22%3A0%2C%22rowIndex%22%3A0%2C%22tableStartLocation%22%3A%7B%22index%22%3A2%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D):**

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateTableCellStyle": {
        "tableCellStyle": {
          "backgroundColor": {
            "color": {
              "rgbColor": {
                "green": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": "backgroundColor",
        "tableRange": {
          "columnSpan": 1,
          "rowSpan": 1,
          "tableCellLocation": {
            "columnIndex": 0,
            "rowIndex": 0,
            "tableStartLocation": {
              "index": 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In my case the index of the table location in the document is 2 - adapt accordingly to your location.

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) This looks promising, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Alright, so I'm getting this `error: Invalid requests[18].updateTableCellStyle: The provided table start location is invalid.` which means that I don't understand this `tableStartLocation` property. I would assume my tableStartLocation would be `index: 0`, as I only have 1 table in my document body. I'm reading here: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#Location I do have a header, and some text before my table starts, would that mean anything? How can I identify this index?

Comment: You can use the method [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get?apix_params=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%22ID%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22body%2Fcontent%2Ftable%2FtableRows%2FstartIndex%22%7D) and retrieve the `startIndex` of the first table row by setting `fields` to `body/content/table/tableRows/startIndex`. The `tableStartLocation index` will be one less than the `tableRows/startIndex`.

Comment: By using the document.get endpoint, and inspecting the content, I find this object, that i assume must be the table:
`{
  startIndex: 88,
  endIndex: 1358,
  table: {
    rows: 15,
    columns: 4,
    tableRows: [....],
    tableStyle: { tableColumnProperties: [Array] }
  }
}`
But when I provide `88` or `87` as `tableStartLocation` I still get the same error: `The provided table start location is invalid.` Any idea?

Comment: This response means that you need to use `87` as index: `"tableStartLocation": {"index": "87"}`

Comment: Interesting, that's exactly what I have been doing. I feel like this issue at hand is slightly off the subject of the original question, so I have created a separate question with a lot more detail and formatted code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526531/the-provided-table-start-location-is-invalid-google-doc-api-batchupdate-node

Comment: In the end it worked out, however, the `tableStartLocation` index must be the same as the  `startIndex` from the inspected document, (not minus 1). I rewrote my code and in the end it worked. I think something weird happened with race condition, I was replacing text while also updating table cells, and I think the indexes might have shifted meanwhile.